# Using teb_local_planner's feedback_msg for control

Tags: ros, navigation, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any potential issues with using the trajectory points from teb_local_planner's /feedback_msg topic as the primary method of control?

By this, I mean that there is a separate node which subscribes to the /feedback_msg topic, and based on the trajectory points, the node calculates a throttle, braking, and steering value to send to the vehicle controllers. /enable_homotopy_class_planning will probably be set to true.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280424/using-teb_local_planner%27s-feedback_msg-for-control/) by [reben](https://answers.ros.org/users/32686/reben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There aren't any issues with using the trajectory points for control to my knowledge.
The feedback message is sent in every computeVelocityCommand() call and hence with the same rate as the conventional twist message (if sending the feedback message is enabled via parameter).

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2018-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0